# Matlab cannot start, error: "Cannot locate com/mathworks/jmi/OpaqueJavaInterface class"

Tags: java, matlab

Hey dear all, I try to start Matlab(version 7.6.0 R2008) and received the error: "Cannot locate com/mathworks/jmi/OpaqueJavaInterface".

I did some googling, and it seems this is related with the jre Matlab is using.

Here is what I have done:
I checked my java project and found that my source lookup path is: "c:\Program Files\Java\jre6", so I added one MATLAB_JAVA environment variable as follows in the advance tab in system property:
MATLAB_JAVA C:\Program FIles\JAVA\Jre6

Still I received this error, How can I solve it?

thank you for your help.

BTW: how can I check this newly added environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like your MATLAB installation is corrupted - it could be that one of the files is missing (in this case, I believe that java class would reside in `<matlab>/java/jar/jmi.jar`). You should also check `<matlab>/toolbox/local/classpath.txt` to see if that has been modified.

It may be simplest to re-install MATLAB.

Comment: Confirmed - I have a working R2008a install, and jmi.jar is where that class lives.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is incorrect: there's no .class file named com.mathworks.jmi.OpaqueJavaInterface in that directory, not in an JAR file it contains.

It's a MATLAB class, so you should find it in a JAR file that ships with MATLAB.  Find out which one and add it to your CLASSPATH for Java.

There are lots of places that tell you how to set CLASSPATH if you don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Either you didn't create an Environment Variable or your java folder has the wrong name in your program files for Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me and I want to share another possible solution.
My version of matlab is 2023b.

And I was getting the following error:

```
Cannot locate or initialize class com/mathworks/jmi/OpaqueJavaInterface.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mathworks/jmi/OpaqueJavaInterface
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mathworks.jmi.OpaqueJavaInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

In my case the file `$matlabroot/java/jar/jmi.jar` actually contained the class OpaqueJavaInterface.

In order to make aware of this class position to matlab I used the `java.opts` file presented in [this documentation page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/java-opts-file.html).
Before that I tried different combination of `classpath.txt` and `javaclasspath.txt` but nothing was working.
So I created the file `$matlabroo/bin/glnxa64/java.opts` the architecture might change depending on your machine.
After that, I included the following line:

`-Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/R2023b/java/jar/jmi.jar`

The path might change depending on the installation folder.
the `/a:` tells to append the following jar file to the classpath if it already exists, in order to not break a previously configured classpath.

Now executing matlab I don't get this java not found error anymore.
I hope this might be helpful for somebody still looking for solutions even if this is an old question.